# Followed Blender Guru's Geometry Node tutorial (gumdrops), have some issues with how it looks

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, geometry-nodes

I followed [the tutorial](https://youtu.be/52UYqe3zdxQ) as closely as possible, have the exact same settings (according to my knowledge) but it does not look nearly as good. It's too transparent. Can someone tell me how to fix it?
(the first one is mine, the second one is the proper one)
[image: My gumdrop]

[image: Blender Guru's one (how it's supposed to look)]

Comment: In the original tutorial IOR of Fresnel is 1.330

Comment: Understand it can be a little daunting as a new user [having questions closed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218859/followed-blender-gurus-geometry-nodes-tutorial-why-does-my-gumdrop-look-so-dif)   It is preferable that you [edit new detail into original](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/218859/edit)  and it will in "all likelyhood" be re-opened.  IMO It would also be preferable if _we_ could hold off downvoting new users posts.

Answer (score 1):

This is the screenshot from the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52UYqe3zdxQ).
I marked things that are wrong in your setup.

[image: Tutorial]